# Wicket : Check of CheckGroup not getting the selected options and perform the submit action

Tags: java, wicket

I'm a newbie to WICKET and got stuck using `PageableListView`.

For selection of individual checkboxes I'm using `Check` and for group selection `CheckGroupSelector`.

Now inspite of using Check if I use CheckBox my code works fine but unable to get selectall working......
Pasting the piece of code for reference.

```
    final CheckGroup<DriveInfo> group = new CheckGroup<DriveInfo>("group", new ArrayList<DriveInfo>());
    driveSearchForm.add(group);
    group.add(new CheckGroupSelector("allSelected"));
    group.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    PageableListView<DashboardModel> pageableListView = new PageableListView<DashboardModel>("searchResults",
            driveDataModel, 50) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<DashboardModel> item) {
            DashboardModel model = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Check("selected", new PropertyModel(model, "selected")));
            item.add(new Label("name", item.getModelObject().getName()));
            item.add(new Label("status", item.getModelObject().getStatus().toString()));
            item.add(new Label("driveUrl", item.getModelObject().getDriveURL()));
        }
    };
    pageableListView.setReuseItems(true);
```

Now instead of

```
item.add(new Check("selected", new PropertyModel(model, "selected")));
```

If I use

```
item.add(new CheckBox("selected", new PropertyModel(model, "selected")));
```

it's working fine......but how should I get selectall(i.e. `CheckGroupSelector`) also working .

Comment: Wicket needs `Check` components to be added (even if indirectly) to a `CheckGroup`. Is there a `group.add(pageableListView)` after the code you posted ?

Comment: Xavi Lopez is correct. CheckGroup needs access to DataView or ListView class (a view class basically) so that when "select all" is clicked it can select all check boxes in the view.

Comment: Yes there is a group.add(pageableListView) after the code i posted.

Comment: Hi Chetan, I am also facing same issue. Could you pls post your solution if you have resolved this issue asap. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The model for `Check` must hold the object which will be inserted into the `CheckGroup` list, in your case, a `DriveInfo` instance. It seems that you are passing a boolean (selected) value, not the object to be selected.